# ERP Linkedin Issue

Tags: hyperlink, linkedin-api, erp, erpnext

Having this issue in erpnext while linking linkedin to erpnext, I have entered all the correct data from linkedin app
Can anyone tell what's the issue or error trying to resolve this but can't understand what's the error init                                                                                                       [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hvb4i.png)